# How do I retrieve a specific keyword from discord message as quickly as possible in Python

Tags: python, optimization, discord

I would like to pick up a specific keyword from a discord message as quickly as possible in Python, I'm currently using a request but the issue is that it takes too much time to actualize and grab the new message (it takes 200-500ms to receive messages), I am sure there is a better way of doing it.

```
def retrieve_messages(channelid):
     while True:
        ##DISCORD   
        headers = {'authorization':""}
        r= requests.get('https://discord.com/api/v9/channels/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/messages',headers=headers)
        jsonn = json.loads(r.text)
     
        for value in jsonn:       
            s1=str(value['content'])
            s2=(re.findall('code:(0x......................)', s1))
            if s2 !=[]:
                print(s2)
retrieve_messages('')
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the reference, the default number of messages returned from the endpoint is 50 (Link: https://discord.com/developers/docs/resources/channel#get-channel-messages). Using the limit-parameter it should be possible to maybe only get 1 or 5, which should limit the amount of time it takes to retrieve the messages and the time it takes to loop through them.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I tried your idea it fixed slightly the optimization issue. But I think the way I am requesting the message is the issue. I tried with WebSocket and the discord gateway, it is more consistent at 200ms. I am sure there is a way to shorten the delay even more.